# Type as a String

Tags: string, reflection, type-conversion, d, compile-time

How do I convert a type to a string?

I thought something like this should work

```
import std.stdio: writeln;
import std.conv: to;
writeln(to!string(int));
```

**Update**: I found it at http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#.fullyQualifiedName

I guess all logic in D operating on types are given as templates arguments right?

Comment: yes, all logic on types would be done with template arguments. With the exception of checking runtime polymorphic types like dynamic cast, or variadic functions (as opposed to the more common variadic template), which is done with TypeInfo instances. You can get typeinfo with the typeid property, but it isn't as generally useful as actually having the type, which is only possible with typeof(var) or template arguments, or typetuples which are really a kind of template argument thingy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `int` is already a type. You don't need to `typeof` it.
2. You could use the `.stringof` property to get a string representation. http://ideone.com/T4yYmo

   ```
   writeln(int.stringof);
   ```

Comment: Aha! So what is the preferred way; `stringof` or `to!string`?

Comment: As I think you discovered, to!string is not an option. stringof is a compiler property which requests the symbols string rep. It is useful when printing template argument tipes T.stringof, in your case writeln("int"); would suffice :)